# Can I use Linux system calls in android?

Tags: android, linux

I want to create a service which can capture the touch coordinates of all the user interactions. This is part of my R & D Project. My goal is to build an authentication system. Can I use linux system calls from my app/service?

Please provide me with some good resources related to linux system calls in Android and how to use them?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you use system calls. One way is you can write your code in C/C++(where you can use ioctl calls) and Use Android NDK for calling C functions or you can Write Wrapper over C functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a limited number of calls, as exposed by the libc implementation for Android.  But, what you indicate you would like to do (capture touch coordinates) will not be possible from a general app, only from within the Android framework.  The input devices are managed by the framework's system_server process, which has the appropriate permissions to access kernel exposed driver interfaces (i.e. /dev/input/*).  Apps developed with the NDK and SDK do not get access to these things as they are sandboxed by UID and process.